# ExecuteReader() in powershell script is not returning any records

Tags: powershell

I have created a function to run ms sql query and return records but the return is not working as it not giving any output

```
function Global:MsSqlQueryExecutor(
                        $SqlQuery,
                        $logfile
                        )
    {   $Global:sqloutreader = $Null
        # make sure that the output from the following code block does not pollute return value
        $Null = @(
                try
                    {
                        $SQLUsername = "abc"
                        $SQLPassword = "abc"
                        $Database = "abc"
                        $SQLServer = "abc"

                        # Define the connection to the SQL Database 
                        $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
                        $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$SQLServer;Database=$Database;User ID=$SQLUsername;Password=$SQLPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=5000;"             

                        $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand                           

                        $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
                        $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
                        $SqlCmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
                        $SqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 2000;

                        Add-Content -Value "$TimeinSec Preparation to execute insertion query: $SqlQuery is completed" -Path $logfile

                        if ($SqlConnection.State -eq [System.Data.ConnectionState]'Closed') 
                            {
                                $SqlConnection.Open()
                            }

                        $Global:sqloutreader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                        Add-Content -Value "$TimeinSec Succeed Execution of the query: $SqlQuery completed" -Path $logfile

                    }
                catch
                    {

                        Add-Content -Value "$TimeinSec Failed to Query: $SqlQuery" -Path $logfile
                        Add-Content -Value $_.Exception.Message -Path $logfile;
                        EXIT

                    }
                finally
                    {
                        $SqlConnection.Close()
                        $SqlConnection.Dispose();
                        Add-Content -Value "$TimeinSec cleanup: Connection is disposed" -Path $logfile
                    }       
                )           
        return $Global:sqloutreader
    }
```

This is the calling part

```
$sqloutreader = MsSqlQueryExecutor($SqlQuery,$logfile)
```

The following while loop is not getting activated . I am not sure what is going wrong here but there is something which I am not able to understand.

```
while($sqloutreader.Read()) 
                    {   
                        $rdrRowCnt++
                        if($rdrRowCnt -gt 1)
                            {
                                Add-Content -Value "$TimeinSec Ambiguity: two Records are found for the current job: $jobname in the $mastTableNm table, hence aborting" -Path $logfile
                                exit
                            }
                        $InputFileLst = $sqloutreader["InputFiles"].Split(";")
                        $OutputFileLst = $sqloutreader["OutputFiles"].Split(";")
                        Add-Content -Value "$TimeinSec Log:Input files:$InputFileLst and outputfiles:$OutputFileLst found for the current job: $jobname in the $mastTableNm table" -Path $logfile
                    }
```

Please help to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried returning `$sqloutreader` within the Try block?

Comment: `$sqloutreader = MsSqlQueryExecutor($SqlQuery,$logfile)` should be `$sqloutreader = MsSqlQueryExecutor $SqlQuery $logfile` as you were passing an array to the first parameter and the second would have been null. Guessing you have logs in the working directory as well as a result. You are surpressing _all_ errors so problems might be hard to trace. Consider using specific catch with specific exception types

Comment: `MsSqlQueryExecutor($SqlQuery,$logfile)` -> `MsSqlQueryExecutor -SqlQuery $SqlQuery -logfile $logfile`

Comment: @Ash I included the return statement within try block and it worked.

Comment: Glad it worked! Thanks for updating with your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewritten the code with return statement inside the try block and it worked.

```
function Global:MsSqlQueryExecutor(
                        $SqlQuery,
                        $logfile
                        )
    {   
        $Global:sqloutreader = $Null
            try
                {
                  # make sure that the output from the following code block does not pollute return value                           
                  $Null = @(    
                        Add-Content -Value "$TimeinSec Log: Setting up the sql query to execute" -Path $logfile

                        $SQLUsername = "aaa"
                        $SQLPassword = "aaa"
                        $Database = "aaa"
                        $SQLServer = "aaa"

                        # Define the connection to the SQL Database 
                        $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
                        $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$SQLServer;Database=$Database;User ID=$SQLUsername;Password=$SQLPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=5000;"             

                        $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand                           

                        $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
                        $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
                        $SqlCmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
                        $SqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 2000;

                        Add-Content -Value "$TimeinSec Log: Preparation to execute query: $SqlQuery is completed" -Path $logfile

                        if ($SqlConnection.State -eq [System.Data.ConnectionState]'Closed') 
                            {
                                $SqlConnection.Open()
                            }

                        $Global:sqloutreader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                        Add-Content -Value "$TimeinSec Log: Execution of the query: $SqlQuery completed successfully" -Path $logfile
                    )
                  return $Global:sqloutreader       
                }
            catch
                {

                    Add-Content -Value "$TimeinSec Error: Failed to Query: $SqlQuery" -Path $logfile
                    Add-Content -Value $_.Exception.Message -Path $logfile;
                    EXIT

                }
            finally
                {
                    $SqlConnection.Close()
                    $SqlConnection.Dispose();
                    Add-Content -Value "$TimeinSec Cleanup: Connection is disposed" -Path $logfile                      
                }   

    }
```